# Are SQL From Subqueries in ElasticSearch SQL API possible?

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, subquery

Is it possible to construct a similar query to the below SQL within ElasticSearch?

```
SELECT Counter, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT serialnumber, COUNT(*) as Counter
FROM "Test-Serial"
GROUP BY serialnumber
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY Counter DESC)
AS SUBQUERY
GROUP BY Counter
```

When I run this I tend to just get the results of the enclosed query instead of the response showing the number of times a count value occurs.

I am after the result of something like:

```
Counter, Counted Counter
1, 2000
2, 140
3, 59
4, 6
```

Which would come from the initial aggregation against a list of serials, that would look something like:

```
Serial, Counted
f3k4f, 2
fk5ir, 1
fk3ir, 1
fk6ir, 2
fk8ir, 4
fk54r, 3
......
```